# How do we decide whether a screen resolution is valid or not?

Tags: display, resolution, desktop

Just out of curiosity, I wanted to know what is criteria upon which the validity of screen resolution like 640x320, 1024x768 etc is determined. I mean why are these only the few resolutions, is that some convention or some technical reasons behind it. Why cant we have say 1000x500 screen res? Or can we?

Comment: It's an age old thing to do with aspect ratios. 640x320 doesn't fit the norm because it's 2:1 but most others are 4:3, 16:9 etc. 4:3 is old and comes from the days of CRT monitors, I believe. Newew ratios are for different widescreens and cinema ratios. If you make a video then you can make it whatever you please, but the display will fit a number defined by frequently used screens and manufacturers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On old CRT displays, you could in theory have any resolution up to the maximum possible on that device. But on LCDs the pixels are physical objects, and any LCD panel has a native resolution that is actually the only possible resolution for that device. Other resolutions are either exact divisors of the physical resolution (e.g. a 2048x1536 panel could display a resolution of 1024x768) or they require interpolation and aliasing that will make the image less sharp. Check the Wikipedia article on [display resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution) for much more information.